How to make visual studio 2022 debug console to use windows terminal
I have the latest:
Windows 11.
Visual studio 2022 preview with all preview settings enabled.
Windows Terminal set as default terminal.
I write a C++ solution that uses NASM to use the console.
The NASM program does nothing. Just start and terminate.
How do I force Visual studio debug console window to use the Windows Terminal?
Tried many ChatGPT and Copilot answers.
Tried many google searches.
None of it worked.

Are you running Visual Studio as administrator? The default terminal functionality doesn't work for applications that are run as administrator.
Does the program work normally when the default terminal is set to "Windows Console Host"?

Yes! I was running VS as Admin by using the RunAsAdmin extension. I disabled it and now it runs perfectly. Thanks man!!! Please write it as a solution and I will accept it as the solution and close it.

Are you running Visual Studio as administrator? The default terminal functionality doesn't work for applications that are run as administrator.
(see also microsoft/terminal#10276 (comment) for additional context)
